# SUM of 2 rows from a different column ordered by 2 different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing this query, I want to be able to take 2 values from different rows under 1 column(Population growth rate) subtract them from each other, and put that value into the new column(PopGrowthRateDiff) for the difference value, making it repeat all the way down, making a null for the 1st value in this new column(since it has no previous number) for each new title/word in the 1st row(Country name).

This is the result I want within an SQL database:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4o1Z96ADgMEDXT1uz1Sn2D/1

Starting from:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jsFB3ELxiX8xp6Xghk21Fe/1

I tried making a temp table to subtract the values individually via 2 different tables. They wouldn't subtract unless they were the same 'year', resulting in a 0 value.

**Query #1(Starting Table)**

| country_name | year | population_growth_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Argentina | 1950 | 1.98 |
| Argentina | 1951 | 1.94 |
| Argentina | 1952 | 1.93 |
| United States | 1950 | 2 |
| United States | 1951 | 2.1 |
| United States | 1952 | 2.05 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jsFB3ELxiX8xp6Xghk21Fe/1)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)(Starting Table source code)**

```
create table test (
  country_name nvarchar(50), 
  year int ,
  population_growth_rate float
);

insert into test
(country_name, year, population_growth_rate)
Values
('Argentina', 1950, 1.98),
('Argentina', 1951, 1.94),
('Argentina', 1952, 1.93),
('United States', 1950, 2.00),
('United States', 1951, 2.10),
('United States', 1952, 2.05);
```

---

**Query #1(Desired Result)**

```
No code to get said result;
```

| country_name | year | population_growth_rate | population_growth_difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Argentina | 1950 | 1.98 |  |
| Argentina | 1951 | 1.94 | 0.04 |
| Argentina | 1952 | 1.93 | 0.01 |
| United States | 1950 | 2 |  |
| United States | 1951 | 2.1 | 0.1 |
| United States | 1952 | 2.05 | -0.05 |

---

Comment: Great work on creating a Fiddle, but the question still needs to be standalone and not dependent on external links, so unfortunately you also need to duplicate the contents of your Fiddle into your question.

Comment: You also need to show us your desired results.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  You could potentially use the LAG() function to achieve your desired result

Comment: You have taged `SQL Server`, but you used a `MySQL` fiddle (with an old version of `MySQL`). What RDBMS and what version do you actually use?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I'm actually working within an SQL server, I'm just not aware of any SQL Server fiddle. I am using SQL Server Management Studio 19.

Comment: SSMS is only a client UI so it's version is not relevant. You need to `select @@version`

Comment: And try dbfiddleuk for SQL server.

Comment: @DaleK Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)   Oct  8 2022 05:58:25   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: ), and thank you for all the information, ill make sure it goes to use on my next post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LAG` to fetch the value from the previous row having the same country_name.

Then build the difference of this previous population_growth_rate and that one of the current row.

If no previous row with the same country_name exists, `NULL` will be returned.

Use `PARTITION BY country_name` to make sure no rows with different country names will be put together:

```
SELECT 
  country_name, [year], population_growth_rate, 
  LAG(population_growth_rate,1)
    OVER(PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY [year]) 
  - population_growth_rate AS population_growth_difference
FROM test;
```

Note 1: `Year` is a SQL keyword, that's why you need to put in in square brackets as shown in the above query. I recommend you rename this column because using SQL key words as table names or column names is bad style.

Note 2: When I try above query on a fiddle, it returns a strange, incorrect value in the last row, see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/70Am6aab).
To be honest, I'm not sure why. I guess this is because of the `FLOAT` datatype. I don't know this well and prefer to use `decimal` instead.
I could solve it using `ROUND`:

```
SELECT 
  country_name, [year], population_growth_rate, 
  ROUND(LAG(population_growth_rate,1)
    OVER(PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY [year]) 
  - population_growth_rate,2) AS population_growth_difference
FROM test;
```

Maybe someone can explain this point better and will leave a comment on this answer.

Note 3: I wonder why the difference is always positive in your desired result. Is this really intended or a mistake? If you really want it like that, you can use `ABS` around your difference to make it positive:

```
SELECT 
  country_name, [year], population_growth_rate, 
  ABS(ROUND(LAG(population_growth_rate,1)
    OVER(PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY [year]) 
  - population_growth_rate,2)) AS population_growth_difference
FROM test;
```

If it's a mistake, check which results should be positive and which negative. Depending on that, it might be necessary to switch the current and the previous value in the query.

Comment: Float is totally the wrong data type as you suspected - it's doesn't store precise values, so aside from scientific data it should not be used

Comment: Them being positive was an oversight on my part, I've primarily been in the actual Server UI and I slapped that together to help get an answer. You are correct they should be negative. Thank you for all the information, I wasn't aware 'lag' and 'lead' was a thing.

Comment: @Lqvy make sure you don't use float also.

Comment: @DaleK Why do floats still exist? As far as I'm aware it used to provide a greater range due to CPU limitations of some sort, but I imagine those limitations have been passed with 64-bit processors.

Comment: @Lqvy nothing to do with limitations - it's for scientific data - and always has been. You need to read up it because it's not precise for regular data.